# Spring doesn't save List in oneToMany relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-data-jpa

I've this Address Entity

```
package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity(name = "addresses")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 3652691377296902875L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;

@Column(length = 30, nullable = false)
private String addressId;

@Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
private String city;

@Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
private String country;

@Column(length = 100, nullable = false)
private String streetName;

@Column(length = 7, nullable = false)
private String postalCode;

@Column(length = 10, nullable = false)
private String type;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
private UserEntity userDetails;

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getAddressId() {
    return addressId;
}

public void setAddressId(String addressId) {
    this.addressId = addressId;
}

public String getCity() {
    return city;
}

public void setCity(String city) {
    this.city = city;
}

public String getCountry() {
    return country;
}

public void setCountry(String country) {
    this.country = country;
}

public String getStreetName() {
    return streetName;
}

public void setStreetName(String streetName) {
    this.streetName = streetName;
}

public String getPostalCode() {

        return postalCode;
    }

    public void setPostalCode(String postalCode) {
        this.postalCode = postalCode;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public UserEntity getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(UserEntity userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

}
```

and this a Users Entity

```
package com.appdeveloperblog.app.ws.io.entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3772691377276902875L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String userId;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 120, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String encryptedPassword;

    private String emailVerificationToken;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean emailVerificationStatus = false;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getEncryptedPassword() {
        return encryptedPassword;
    }

    public void setEncryptedPassword(String encryptedPassword) {
        this.encryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
    }

    public String getEmailVerificationToken() {
        return emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationToken(String emailVerificationToken) {
        this.emailVerificationToken = emailVerificationToken;
    }

    public Boolean getEmailVerificationStatus() {
        return emailVerificationStatus;
    }

    public void setEmailVerificationStatus(Boolean emailVerificationStatus) {
        this.emailVerificationStatus = emailVerificationStatus;
    }

}
```

and this function which I use it in service layer to save the data into the Mysql Database

```
@Override
    public UserDto createUser(UserDto user) {

        if (userRepository.findByEmail(user.getEmail()) != null)
            throw new RuntimeException("Record already exists");

        for(int i = 0 ; i < user.getAddresses().size() ; i++)
        {
            AddressDTO address = user.getAddresses().get(i);
            address.setUserDetails(user);
            address.setAddressId(utils.generateAddressId(30));
            user.getAddresses().set(i, address);
        }

        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(user, UserEntity.class);

        String publicUserId = utils.generateUserId(30);

        userEntity.setUserId(publicUserId);
        userEntity.setEncryptedPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

        UserEntity storedUserDetails = userRepository.save(userEntity);

        // BeanUtils.copyProperties(storedUserDetails, returnValue);

        UserDto returnValue = modelMapper.map(storedUserDetails, UserDto.class);

        return returnValue;
    }
```

after I post the data to the API using Postman POST request it save only the data into the users table and all the data in addresses table have been igonred

POST request Example:

```
{
"firstName" : "Sergey",
"lastName" : "Kargopolov",
"email" : "tno@test.com",
"password" : "123",
"addresses":[
    {
        "city":"Vancouver",
        "country":"Canada",
        "streetName":"123 Street name",
        "postalCode": "ABCBA",
        "type":"billing"
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below classes are the stripped down version of what you are trying to achieve. Please compare with your classes and it should work fine only difference is I have remove additional fields to test it easily. Check code in **UserController** map method.

**UserEntity.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4865903039190150223L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(length = 50, nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userDetails", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<AddressEntity> addresses;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<AddressEntity> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "UserEntity [id=" + id + ", firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", addresses="
                + addresses + "]";
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<AddressEntity> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

}
```

**AddressEntity.java**

```
@Entity(name = "addresses")
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3652691377296902875L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @Column(length = 15, nullable = false)
    private String country;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "users_id")
    private UserEntity userDetails;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public UserEntity getUserDetails() {
        return userDetails;
    }

    public void setUserDetails(UserEntity userDetails) {
        this.userDetails = userDetails;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AddressEntity [id=" + id + ", city=" + city + ", country=" + country + "]";
    }

}
```

**UserDto.java**

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6835192601898364280L;
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<AddressDTO> addresses;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public List<AddressDTO> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    public void setAddresses(List<AddressDTO> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

}
```

**AddressDTO.java**

```
public class AddressDTO {

    private long id;

    private String city;

    private String country;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    @PostMapping("map")
    @ResponseBody
    public UserEntity map(@RequestBody UserDto userDto) {
        ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
        UserEntity userEntity = modelMapper.map(userDto, UserEntity.class);
        for (AddressEntity address : userEntity.getAddresses()) {
            address.setUserDetails(userEntity);
        }
        repository.save(userEntity);
        return userEntity;
    }
}
```

**Sample Request:**

```
{
"firstName" : "Sergey",
"lastName" : "Kargopolov",
"addresses":[
    {
        "city":"Vancouver",
        "country":"Canada"
    }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "id": 7,
    "firstName": "Sergey",
    "lastName": "Kargopolov",
    "addresses": [
        {
            "id": 8,
            "city": "Vancouver",
            "country": "Canada"
        }
    ]
}
```